# search image from google in react-native

Tags: react-native, google-image-search

I have a problem, need to search image from google using  react-native api ?
p/s: I do not learn English well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfMop.png)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/image-search/

Comment: The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be limited. i tired :(